# Spring MVC, how to pass an object from JSP to Controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this code below in my JSP :

```
<c:forEach var="resultDisplay" items="${listResultDisplay}">
            <form:form method="POST"
                    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/display" modelAttribute="resultDisplay">
                    <!-- create an html table row -->
                    <tr>
                        <!-- create cells of row -->
                        <td>${resultDisplay.date}</td>
                        <td>${resultDisplay.documentDisplays[0].idNumber}</td>
                        <td>${resultDisplay.siret}</td>
                        <td align="center">

                             <input type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-success" value="Rechercher" name="sync"
                            id="monSubmit" /></td>

                        <!-- close row -->
                    </tr>
                    <!-- close the loop -->
                </form:form>
            </c:forEach>
```

I have a Controller that initialized a List of object "resultDisplay".
I iterate on every object of the List.

When i submit it, it send my object to a new Controller :

```
@Controller
public class ResultController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/display", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView displayResult(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            @ModelAttribute("resultDisplay") ResultDisplay resultDisplay) {

        return new ModelAndView("display", "result", resultDisplay);
    }

}
```

My object nerver appears in my controller....
When i'm in Debug mode, the object is null in my controller

PS: I juste want to send my object to a new JSP throught this controller, i don't need to manipulate it

Comment: Did you check the request url/payload in the browser debugger? Is it proper? Are you getting any errors in the logs regarding mapping of request payload, resultDisplay, to the displayResult method? You can enable Spring debug/trace logging and use breakpoint to see whats is going on.

Comment: Yes i check everything (log, POST request, etc...)
There's no errors...
It return my page correctly but no object is send